# Float subnav UL in horizontal center of parent LI

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists

I have a primary nav system which has child nested ULs within the parent UL - e.g. see code example below.

```
<ul>
<li>1st level button 1</li>
<li>1st level button 2</li>
<li>1st level button 3
<ul id="thisone">
<li>2nd level button 1</li>
<li>2nd level button 1</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>1st level button 4</li>
</ul>
```

What I am looking to do is get the subnav (e.g. child), UL to sit in the horizontal center of it's parent LI - So UL #thisone would sit horizontally centered below ist level button 3 LI.

So, I think I need to work out the width of the 1st Level 3 LI, then half that and use left:-XXpx (half the width of the 1st Level 3 LI) to make UL #thisone sit horizontally centered below it... e.g. from the middle axis...

Does that make sense?

The nav system is dynamic so I need to be able to work out the width of the parent LI relative to the UL that is being rendered... Happy to do this in jQuery btw...

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Comment: Are the 1st level button vertical (one on top of the other) or horizontal (next to each other)? and (#thisone li)'s are vertical or horizontal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, jQuery would make things a bit more easier.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>1st level button 1</li>
    <li>1st level button 2
        <ul>
            <li>2nd level button 1</li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>1st level button 3
        <ul>
            <li>2nd level button 1</li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>1st level button 4</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
}

li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    position:relative;
}

.nav {
    background:grey;
}

/*.sub-nav {*/
.nav > li > ul {
    background:green;
    position:absolute;
    white-space:nowrap;
    left:50%;
    display:none;
}

.nav > li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".nav > li > ul").each(function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    var leftMargin = "-" + ( $element.width() / 2 ) + "px";
    $element.css("margin-left", leftMargin);
});
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/R5D7s/2/

Comment: Thanks - seems to work well, but the issue I have is that in the example code I referenced <ul class="sub-nav"> to make it easy to identity it for demo purposes - in real life this UL is not with a class name and there are many of them -each with a different LI parent which has a unique width. Any ideas on how to tweak the suggestion to work this way?

Comment: Will make the selectors a bit ugly but it should work, updated my answer with new fiddle -cheers

Comment: Thanks - works great - I had a fixed width on my subnav UL which was messing things up but ironed it out now... Thanks!